# Pandas adding in a second decimal when reading in repeated float values in a single row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to combine several csv files into one large one, 400 in total. The files contain varying amounts of rows but the same amount of columns. I can get them into one single file together but some repeated values in a row are adding a second decimal place that I don't want.

The input data might contain:
..., 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, ...
And after reading it in and writing to the csv it becomes:
..., 0.000, 0.000.1, 0.000.2, ...

It also seems to do this at random as some of the rows are completely okay.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = "trainingData"
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

counter = 0

for f in csv_files:
    print("File: {} of 402".format(counter))
    counter+=1

    df = pd.read_csv(f, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=', ')
    print(df.head(5))
    df.to_csv("allData.csv", index=False, na_rep="0", mode='a', lineterminator='\r\n', float_format='%.3f')
```

example input row:

> 

```
1, 5000.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 180.356, -67.467, -167.262, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1068.000, 5000.0, 509.523, -1290.843, -405.013, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0
```

Whats written back out to the file:

> 

```
1, 5000.0, 0.0, 0.000, 0.000.1, 0.000.2, 180.356, -67.467, -167.262, 0.000.3, 0.000.4, 0.000.5, 1068.000, 5000.0.1, 509.523, -1290.843, -405.013, 0.000.6, 0.000.7, 0.000.8, 0.000.9, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = "trainingData"
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

counter = 0

for f in csv_files:
    print("File: {} of 402".format(counter))
    counter+=1

df = pd.read_csv(f, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=', ')
print(df.head(5))
# Remove the mode='a' flag
df.to_csv("allData.csv", index=False, na_rep="0", lineterminator='\r\n', float_format='%.3f')
```

Comment: Removing that just made the to_csv overwrite the file each time so it only has the data of the last file. :(

Answer (score 0):

After trying a bunch of different things I finally found that it was reading those rows in as headers. So, pandas was trying to fix the columns having the same name by appending the .X.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = "trainingData"
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

counter = 0

for f in csv_files:
    print("File: {} of 402".format(counter))
    counter+=1

    # Specify there is no header Here 
    df = pd.read_csv(f, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=', ', header=None)
    print(df.head(5))
    df.to_csv("allData.csv", index=False, na_rep="0", mode='a', lineterminator='\r\n', float_format='%.3f')
```